# FizzBuzz giving back random numbers when using getElementById.innerHTML

Tags: function, if-statement, getelementbyid, fizzbuzz

Hopefully someone can help me out here. I'm very new to coding and learning to write my first fizzbuzz. My code works when I execute it using console.log, but when I try to use getElementById.innerHTML it wants to give back random numbers.

Here's what I'm working with:

```js
function clickAlert2() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 140; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        i + ". National Gamers <br>";
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML += i + ". National <br>";
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML += i + ". Gamers <br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML += i;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
  .button2 {
  background-color: #FAD7A0;
  color: #21618C;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button2" value="Print 140 Lines" onclick="clickAlert2()">
<br>
<div id="ngList"></div>
```

I think it's just something minor, but I have no clue what it could be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not giving back random randoms, but rather the `i` values which are not divisible by either 3 or 5 (or both) did not receive `<br>` newlines in the HTML.  If you add a `<br>` to the `else` case, your input appears what you would expect.

```js
function clickAlert2() {
    for (var i=1; i <= 140; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
                i + ". National Gamers <br>";
        }
        else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML += i + ". National <br>";
        }
        else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML += i + ". Gamers <br>";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.button2 {
    background-color: #FAD7A0;
    color: #21618C;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button2" value="Print 140 Lines" onclick="clickAlert2()">
<br>
<div id="ngList"></div>
```

Note sure if you even want to print the non matching lines.  If you don't, then the `else` condition should be removed entirely.

Comment: I knew it was something simple! Thanks Tim, I spent a little longer on this than I should have!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a break to the else, so it print numbers on the same line. First line is 123, not a random number, but the first three numbers on a single line.

```js
function clickAlert2() {
  var element = document.getElementById("ngList");

  for (var i = 1; i <= 140; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      element.innerHTML += i + ". National Gamers";
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      element.innerHTML += i + ". National";
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      element.innerHTML += i + ". Gamers";
    } else {
      element.innerHTML += i;
    }
    element.innerHTML += "<br>";
  }
}
```

```css
  .button2 {
  background-color: #FAD7A0;
  color: #21618C;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button2" value="Print 140 Lines" onclick="clickAlert2()">
<br>
<div id="ngList"></div>
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Guess I missed the new answers have been posted while i was writing it.